# Bringup Turtlebot3

Tags: rviz, turtlebot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I accidentally connect wrong wire to the opencr board which caused a short and may damage the board. When I bring up the turtlebot, this red items showed up on RViz. Are they related to the motors?

**wheel_left_link**

**wheel_right_link**

[image: image description]

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/267566/bringup-turtlebot3/) by [rozoalex](https://answers.ros.org/users/31065/rozoalex/) on ROS Answers with karma: 113 on 2017-07-27

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-07-28**:
Is this a duplicate of #q267562? Or the other way around?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If the OpenCR board is damaged the lack of wheel odometry would be expected.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2017-11-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0